# Changing column name dynamically

Tags: c#, acumatica

I have a Header / Detail custom screen where I'm manipulating which grid columns display based on a dropdown selection in the header.  This works fine, but now I'd like to change a few column names as well.  Using the documented syntax, I cannot get this to work.  I can't see what I'm doing wrong - nothing seems to make any difference.  I've attached to process and put a break point at this event, and it's hitting the line - but the system seems to just ignore it:

```
    protected virtual void ACMappingHeader_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        var mh = (ACMappingHeader)e.Row;
        if (mh == null) return;

        if (mh.MappingType == "Option1")
        {
            PXUIFieldAttribute.SetDisplayName<ACMappingDetail.target1CD>(this.MappingDetail.Cache, "Target");
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your display name routine looks correct however to make sure the column names actually update you need to do the following:

- In the page source, you need to set the "RepaintColumns=true" value on the grid.   This can be done via customization manager or directly from your ASPX source.  - This tells the grid to refresh the columns after a callback allowing the headers to actually redisplay.

Comment: That repaint = true was it - thanks.  I knew I was missing something

Answer (score 1):

You can refer below example to dynamically change Grid Column Header.

Below example works with Screen PM401000 – Project Transactions Inquiry

```
public class TransactionInquiryExt : PXGraphExtension<TransactionInquiry>
{
    public void TranFilter_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected baseInvoke)
    {
        if (baseInvoke != null)
            baseInvoke(cache, e);

        PX.Objects.PM.TransactionInquiry.TranFilter row = e.Row as PX.Objects.PM.TransactionInquiry.TranFilter;

        if (row == null) return;

        PXUIFieldAttribute.SetDisplayName<PMTran.description>(Base.Transactions.Cache,
            row.ProjectID.HasValue ? "Description for Project Tran" : "Description");
    }
}
```

Make sure to set `RepaitColumns` property to True of `PXGrid` Control.

[image]