# Change Background color of column in grid dynamically

Tags: acumatica

Hi I don't know how to dynamically change the background color of the column inside the grid I tried looking here [Changing column name dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37838922/changing-column-name-dynamically) but failed. I also tried looking for something like change but only changing of display name is applicable.

```
 PXUIFieldAttribute.SetDisplayName<PMTran.description>(Base.Transactions.Cache,
        row.ProjectID.HasValue ? "Description for Project Tran" : "Description");
```

Comment: I had that request once before.  I don't remember the details, but I was forced to add code in the code-behind file of the actual aspx page.  Investigate the screen EP404000, specifically the code behind file.

Comment: Okay will do.. @ChrisH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out for the answer:
[How to change the cell colors](http://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/12/using-colors-in-acumatica.html)