# Change the field DisplayName dynamically based on certain condtion

Tags: acumatica

I know that in the constructor of the BLC, we can change the displayname by the static method

> PXUIFieldAttribute.SetDisplayName<>

```
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetDisplayName<FIELD>(sender, "NEW VALUE");
```

I tried to change in row selected event of my documents header record. But it doesn't seem to work. Is it possible to change this value in some rowseleted event or after initialization?

Answer (score 3):

In order to change field display name on a form at run-time you could:

**-Add new unbound field to the DAC.** (as readonly)

```
  [PXString(60, IsUnicode = true)]
  [PXUIField(Enabled = false, IsReadOnly = true)]
  public virtual string UsrReadOnlyAcctName{get;set;}
  public abstract class usrReadOnlyAcctName : IBqlField{}
```

**-Modify its value depending on conditions using handlers.** ( Example: on customer statement cycle ID selected)

```
 public class CustomerMaint_Extension:PXGraphExtension<CustomerMaint>
  {

      protected void Customer_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
      {
          var customer = (BAccount)e.Row;
          var customerExt = customer.GetExtension<BAccountExt>();
          if (customerExt != null)
          {
              customerExt.UsrReadOnlyAcctName = customer.AcctName;
          }
      }

  }
```

**-SuppressLabel(true) for both new unbound fields and existing fields whose label will be replace.**

[image]

**-Locate/Put the added Unbound field before the existing field.**

For the Details or PXGrid just make sure to set **RepaitColumns** property to True of *PXGrid* Control.

For the Details a similar question has been answered on this one: [Changing column name dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37838922/changing-column-name-dynamically)

Comment: so this is a workaround to use an unbound field other than actually changing the display name. Thanks @cb

Comment: Yes, you are right this is a workaround with unbound fields! Unfortunately the PXUIField does not have ASPX field property similar to “RepaintColumns” that we use for grid.

Comment: Just an additional point - it seems you need to put the 'label' field and the actual field inside a Merge layout rule with a start group and end group - but the 'label' still looks offset from the left by a few spaces and also has an underline, making it look terrible.  Am I missing something?